# Dynamic URLs for the <ion-tab>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am the beginner of ionic and is stuck in one stage, I want to use tab view to display different portion of a shopping list and their corresponding urls are

products page: "/list/:listId/products"
stores page : "/list/:listId/stores"
price page: "/list/:listId/stores"

and the corresponding routes are listed as above

```
$stateProvider

  //all lists page as the starter point
  .state('allLists', {
    url: '/all-lists',
    templateUrl: 'templates/all-lists.html',
    controller: 'AllListsCtrl'
  })

  //add list page
  .state('addList', {
    url: '/add-list',
    templateUrl: 'templates/add-list.html',
    controller: 'AddListCtrl'
  })

  //tab view for list, abstract state setting up
  .state('list', {
    url: '/list/:listId',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'
  })

  //products page for list
  .state('list.products', {
    url: '/products', 
    views: {
      'list-products': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/list-products.html',
        controller: 'ListProductsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  //store page for list
  .state('list.stores', {
    url: '/stores',
    views: {
      'list-stores': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/list-stores.html',
        controller: 'ListStoresCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  //price page for list
  .state('list.price', {
    url: '/price',
    views: {
      'list-price': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/list-price.html',
        controller: 'ListPriceCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

However, in "templates/list.html", I try to do the following things

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Products Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Products" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/list/{{listId}}/products">
    <ion-nav-view name="list-products"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Stores Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Stores" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/list/{{listId}}/stores">
    <ion-nav-view name="list-stores"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Price Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Price" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/list/{{listId}}/price">
    <ion-nav-view name="list-price"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

But the link returned is "#/list//price" and "#/list//stores" 
So, my question is, how to assign the listId into the  elements?

Comment: You should probably be using `ui-sref` instead of `href`. For instance, `ui-sref="list" ui-sref-opts="{listId: 5}"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one can be a little bit tricky.

First of all you need to change your **abstract** state so it does not cache or you might not be able to see the elements in the list, after the first visit:

```
.state('list', {
    url: '/list/:listId',
    abstract: true,
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
    controller: 'mainListCtrl'
})
```

As you can see I've used `cache: false`.
I've also added a controller cause we need to route the `listId`:

```
.controller("mainListCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams){
  $scope.listId = $stateParams.listId;
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
    console.log('mainListCtrl', $stateParams);
  });
})
```

This controller doesn't do much; it just gets the `:listId` parameter and saves it in the `$scope` so it can be read by your list (view).

and this is how your `templates/list.html` should look like:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Products Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Products" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" ui-sref="list.products({ listId: listId })">
    <ion-nav-view name="list-products"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Stores Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Stores" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" ui-sref="list.stores({ listId: listId })">
    <ion-nav-view name="list-stores"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Price Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Price" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" ui-sref="list.price({ listId: listId })">
    <ion-nav-view name="list-price"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Notice I've changed the `href` to `ui-sref` cause it gives you better flexibility in terms of knowing which route you're referencing:

```
ui-sref="list.products({ listId: listId })"
ui-sref="list.stores({ listId: listId })"
ui-sref="list.price({ listId: listId })"
```

Each one of these references loads the appropriate state (and view) using their name and passing the parameter `listId` which we have previously saved in the `$scope` of the controller `mainListCtrl` (abstract state):

```
.controller("mainListCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams){
  $scope.listId = $stateParams.listId;
})
```

I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqfszeiw75KbmkKlpYXW?p=preview) where you can see how it works.

PS: You can try and change the cache to `cache: true` for the state list and see how the behaviour changes, only showing the first element you have selected in the "All Lists" view.